# one-time variable assignment in Bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to understand how the one-time variable assignment needs to be done correctly in Bash. Please consider the following two examples, where I was expecting to get the same result in Bash:

```
unset Var 
Var=123 echo $Var
# prints nothing
```

I now edit the file **test.sh** with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $Var
```

and execute:

```
unset Var 
Var=123 source test.sh
# prints 123
```

Can somebody please explain why there is different behavior in these two examples?

Thanks!

Comment: you need a `;` in between the variable assignment and the `echo` for it to work

Comment: @Jetchisel the change you suggest produces two different statements. The question is about the one-time environment variables used with the current statement.